Automate the removal of the VS Code Welcome screen with PowerShell
I setup a portable version of VS Code when I start my Windows Sandbox instances. This works well, however, after every Sandbox restart, when I start VS Code, I get the Welcome screen, so it gets a bit annoying to see it. The Sandbox Settings.json is located at C:\Users\WDAGUtilityAccount\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\data\user-data\User
I thought that this might do the trick to remove it, but this fails.
{
    "welcome.enable":  false,
}

How can we use PowerShell to automatically disable the VS Code Welcome screen (possibly in the settings.json after unzipping the VS Code archive and setting up my VS Code shortcuts (which I also do with PowerShell, so being able to disable the Welcome screen in the same script would be great)? I need this to be automated because I download the latest version of VS Code whenever it comes out so manually going into VS Code, clicking away the Welcome screen, then zipping that copy up is really not much use as ends up with the same problem of having to manually do this every time a new version comes out.

Try "workbench.startupEditor": "none",? the default is welcomePage. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/47087029/7411885
